# For Gazelle, how can I make it use go_repository defined in the WORKSPACE?

Tags: go, bazel

In my WORKSPACE, I have defined the go_repostitory for importpath golang.org/x/net.

```
go_repository(
   name = "org_golang_x_net",
   commit = "5ccada7d0a7ba9aeb5d3aca8d3501b4c2a509fec",
   importpath = "golang.org/x/net",
)
```

But when I run gazelle, the dependency added to BUILD.Bazel is not @org_golang_x_net//context:go_default_library. Instead, it is the following: //golang.org/x/net/context:go_default_library

Why does gazelle ignore the defined go_repository? Is there a way for it to consider deps defined in WORKSPACE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48303948/for-gazelle-how-can-i-drop-src-from-the-generated-importpath) this is because you're using an empty prefix.

Gazelle resolves Go imports to Bazel labels in several steps:

1. If there is a `go_library` in your workspace with a matching `importpath`, Gazelle will use the name of that library.
2. If the import path is below the top-level prefix for your repository, the import will be considered "local", so you'll get a label like `//golang.org/x/net/content:go_default_library`.

   - Since you're using an empty prefix at the top level, this catch will catch every unknown import.
   - This should be improved. Gazelle's resolver should be aware of prefixes defined in different directories (currently, those are only used to determine the `importpath` attribute on generated rules). I've filed [bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle#101](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/issues/101) to fix that.
3. If the import is not considered local, Gazelle will generate a label for an external repository or for the vendor directory, depending on the external mode.

For now, you may want to add a directive to your top-level build file like:

```
# gazelle:prefix __do_not_match__
```

This will basically disable the second case, since no import will start with that. You'll still have an empty prefix in your src directory (set with `# gazelle:prefix` in src/BUILD.bazel), so your libraries will still have the correct `importpath` directives. You might want to set that to more specific subdirectories though.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I was not able to use your suggested fix as stated. Adding # gazelle:prefix __do_not_match__ to the root build didnt help - unless I did it wrong. However in the root build, I had specified gazelle config and I set the prefix in that to __do_not_match__. After that I was able to get rid off all the #keep I had around deps. Some imports were unrecognized - appengine & appengine_internal. That is probably because go code in appengine world seems to follow its own conventions. However, the non-appengine bazel BUILDs work great!